# How to count rows in table in MVC - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, for-loop, foreach, count, row

I have this foreach code in my View in MVC4:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Variables)
{
 <td>@row.Variable1.FirstOrDefault()</td>
 <td>@row.Variable2.FirstOrDefault()</td>  
}
```

Now I whant to write in each row number (sequential number).

I have try with this code:

```
@if (Model.Spremenljivke != null)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var row in Model.Spremenljivke)
    {
        <tr align="center">
            <td>@i</td>
            <td>@row.Internal.First()</td>
            <td>@row.Exchangetimestamp.Add(Model.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)</td>
            <td>@row.Order.First()</td>
            <td>@row.MsgT.First()</td>
            <td>@row.Exchangetimestamp2.Add(Model.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)</td>
            i++;
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="7"><hr/></td></tr>

    }
}
```

Problem is that returns this:

```
i++;i++;i++ ...
Column i
0
0
0
0
...
```

Comment: Why you don't do the same thing done in seconth example? Simple declare var i = 0; i++ and print i each time.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I have done this: before Foreach I have write var i = 0; then in <td>@i++</td> ?

Comment: Yes, I think this can be a good solution (if I understand your question).

Comment: I have try this and in <td> returns me: 0++

Answer (score 1):

I'l try answer your question with your example modified:

```
@{ var i  = 0; }
@foreach (var row in Model.Variables)
{
 <td>@i.ToString()</td>
 <td>@row.Variable1.FirstOrDefault()</td>
 <td>@row.Variable2.FirstOrDefault()</td>  
 @i++;
}
```

I've added var necessary to increment and show row num. You can write directly "i++" because you are in foreach statement managed by razord and @ is not necessary.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: :( it does not work, it puts 0 in each row and i++ as text above table  in one row (not in table), something like this: i++;i++;i++;... but so many time as I have rows in my table (15).

Comment: Do you think that is problem in my Variables, because they are multivalued, it meany that tey can be zero or some value? That is why returns me only zeros?

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is too strange. I've tested the foreach using a standard array (String), i is displayed correctly.

Comment: Do you think that problem is in Model.Variables? Because I am returning a group value from controler to Model.Variables. But, still, this should not be problem.

Comment: Please, Add @ before i var name (this will be: @i++ and not i++).

Comment: same result, 0++,0+++ etc. txn for help